# How to set firefox so that it asks for profile while opening?

Tags: firefox, user-profile

How to set Firefox so that it will ask choose profile while running Firefox ? Can i edit the Firefox binary for the same ? if yes, how can it be possible ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### If you are *not* using Unity

- Copy the global `firefox.desktop` file to `~/.local/share/applications`:

  ```
  cp /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
  ```
- Open the local copy with `gedit`:

  ```
  gedit ~/.local/share/applications/firefox.desktop
  ```
- Look for the *first* line, starting with `Exec=`

  Change it into

  ```
  Exec=firefox -P
  ```
- Log out and back in, now when you run firefox, it will show:

  [image]

#### If you *are* using Unity:

There is another option to conveniently choose between profiles:

[image]

Add both profiles to the firefox quicklist.

#### To do so

- copy the global `firefox.desktop` file to `~/.local/share/applications`:

  ```
  cp /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
  ```
- Then open the local copy:

  ```
  gedit ~/.local/share/applications/firefox.desktop
  ```

  and look for the line:

  ```
  Actions=NewWindow;NewPrivateWindow;
  ```

  [I'll use ***default*** and ***TestTest*** as examples for your profiles, replace the names by your real profile names.]

  Change the line into:

  ```
  Actions=NewWindow;NewPrivateWindow;default;TestTest;
  ```
- Now add the following section to the very bottom of the file:

  ```
  [Desktop Action TestTest]
  Name=TestTest
  Exec=firefox -P TestTest
  OnlyShowIn=Unity;

  [Desktop Action default]
  Name=default
  Exec=firefox -P default
  OnlyShowIn=Unity;
  ```
- log out and back in, your Firefox launcher should look like in the image,
  and you can choose from which profile to open a new window.

---

### EDIT

As requested by OP, an additional section. The solution above works fine, but *new* windows are opened in the same profile.

To avoid that, add another item to your `firefox` quicklist, to open a new window with an arbitrary profile. To do so:

1. Open the local `firefox.desktop` file that you created (copied), as described in the answer.
2. Look (again) for the line:

   ```
   Actions=NewWindow;NewPrivateWindow;default;TestTest;
   ```

   change it into:

   ```
   Actions=NewWindow;NewPrivateWindow;default;TestTest;New window with profile;
   ```
3. Add to the very end of your file a section:

   ```
   [Desktop Action New window with profile]
   Name=New window with profile
   Exec=firefox -new-instance -P
   OnlyShowIn=Unity;
   ```

Now you can choose to open a new window in a specific profile:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the help. It works well, but now there is one issue like when i open a second firefox without closing the first one it doesn't asks for profile and automatically opens the same profile in which the first one opened. Is there any way to set firefox so that is will asks for profile for each new firefox jobs.

Comment: Sorry, I think i already put the tick on the big "V". If it is not enough or it is not correct please let me know what else should i do because iam new to here, and i don't know the procedures here.

Comment: For me, it was asking the profile only if no Firefox window was open, but I wanted it to always ask, even if another window was already open, as in Rooney's case. The first solution solved my problem. I'm using Linux Mint 21.2 Cinnamon.

Comment: Update: this breaks links clicked from other apps. Instead of opening the page on Firefox, it asks for the profile and then opens an empty tab.

Answer (score 2):

Or when you don't want to change your desktop files you can simply edit `~/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini` and change line:

```
StartWithLastProfile=1
```

to:

```
StartWithLastProfile=0
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally i managed to edit the binary of Firefox to get the profile while opening.

Open  `/usr/bin/firefox` file in any text editor with `sudo` privilege and edit the last part of the file.

After editing that file would be look like this.

```
else
    exec $MOZ_LIBDIR/$MOZ_APP_NAME -P --no-remote "$@"
fi
```

Thats all. After saving the file when you open Firefox it will ask for profile.